# Why won't my constructor re-initialize variables when the loop executes?

Tags: c++, class, loops, constructor

My tic-tac-tow board maintains the same values as the last game, instead of reinitializing to the values it is supposed to be assigned in the constructor. (123, 456, 789)

Does anyone have a clue why this may be?

**Constructor:**

```
ticTacToe:: ticTacToe()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            board[i][j] = 49 + (i + j);

     for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            board[i][j] = 51 + (i + j);

     for (int i = 2; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            board[i][j] = 53 + (i + j);

     player = 1;
     validMove = true;
     gameOver = false;
     winner = 0;
     p1win = 0;
     p2win = 0;
     tie = 0;
}
```

**member function:**

```
void ticTacToe:: gameLoop()
{
    do
    {
    ticTacToe();
    print();
    getMove();
    alternatePlayer();
    winGameCheck();
    endGameCheck();
    }
    while (!gameOver);
    endPrint();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ticTacToe();
```

This constructs a temporary `ticTacToe` object then destroys that temporary object.  It doesn't actually "re-call" the constructor of the current object.

I think the correct approach here would be to provide a "`reset()`" function that redraws the game board.  That said, even that doesn't make sense since you'd be resetting the game every turn.

Answer (score 2):

You're not calling the constructor, you're actually creating a new object and losing a reference to it. For example:

```
ticTacToe obj = ticTacToe();
//              ^----------- you're doing this, but not assigning it to anything
```

You want to separate the stuff inside your constructor into a different method, such as `init` or `reset`, and call that method from the constructor and from within the game loop.